# Number of patterns to $k$-color $n$ distinguishable boxes with the $k!$ combintations of colors of a pattern considered the same

Tags: combinatorics

There are $k$ colors to choose from to color $n$ distinguishable boxes. However the restriction is permutations from swapping out colors with each other are considered one pattern. Each of the $k$ colors must be used $(n \ge k)$.

For example, to color $5$ boxes with $3$ colors:

Let $R, G, B$ be the colors.

$(R, R, G, G, B), (G, G, R, R, B), (G, G, B, B, R)$ will be considered the same pattern.

But $(R, R, G, G, B)$ and $(R, G, R, G, B)$ are considered different patterns.

Note: when $k = n$, there is only $1$ pattern. $(n, k) = (5, 3)$ gives $25$ patterns

How many patterns are there in this way? A bonus would be writing a program to generate such patterns.

Comment: This looks to be [Stirling numbers of the second kind](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stirling_numbers_of_the_second_kind).

Comment: I’m new to that and not sure if it’s a coincidence that the $n=5, k=2$ example gives the same answer. Also, how does the unlabelled non-empty subsets account for the order of my RRGGB, RGRGB example?

Comment: The first example is three instances of the partition $\{\{1,2\}, \{3,4\}, \{5\}\}$ and the second one has the partition $\{\{1,3\}, \{2,4\},\{5\}\},$ which is different.